# Stages to remove repeated value from a file in datastage

Tags: datastage

Which stage can be used to remove duplicate values from a file in DataStage other than remove duplicate and Stage properties partitioning by selecting unique? How to perform it?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Sort stage and use unique settings in Properties
2. And use transformer in sequence and keep checking the incoming rows whether they are dups or not, if yes, do not pass to output else pass

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to remove duplicates other than using Remove Duplicates Stage. As stated above you can use Sort stage, Transformer stage.

In sort stage, you can enable Key Change() column and it will be useful to filter the duplicate records.

You can use Aggregator stage to remove duplicates. Here you need 2 more stages copy and join stages. Even we can capture the [duplicate records using remove duplicate stage](http://wingsoftechnology.com/capture-duplicates-using-remove-duplicate-stage-in-datastage/).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is use filter option in sequential file stage properties. In the filter box give the Unix command sort -u and the work is done